# Disabling smooth scrolling in OS X Lion when using page up/down

Tags: macos, osx-lion, scrolling

In OS X Lion, when I hit the page up/down keys in browsers (Chrome, Safari), the page doesn't instantly jump as I'd like it to; instead, the page smoothly scrolls into position. I find that distracting. How can I disable it so that it jumps when I use the page up/down keys, I don't watch it scroll?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lion and earlier versions of OS X have an option to disable smooth scrolling in the General or Appearance preference pane.

On Mountain Lion you can run `defaults write -g NSScrollAnimationEnabled -bool false`. Applying changes requires reopening applications.

Comment: Still works in macOS Big Sur!