# Disable Chrome 43 smooth scroll

Tags: google-chrome, osx-mavericks, scrolling

I recently upgraded to Chrome 43 and I've noticed that it unpleasantly smooth scrolls on all keyboard scrolling action (space bar, page up / down, home / end). Is there any way to disable this annoying behaviour?

I'm on Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) if it's any help.

Comment: I don’t have my MacBook available atm, but did you check in `about:flags`? On Windows, I don’t see any smooth scrolling at all.

Comment: I did check but found nothing of interest.

Comment: This worked for me: http://superuser.com/a/466320/389058

Comment: Relevant: [Mavericks: how to disable responsive scroll](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/106783)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling smooth scrolling in OS X Lion when using page up/down](http://superuser.com/questions/466039/disabling-smooth-scrolling-in-os-x-lion-when-using-page-up-down)